# How can I diff a branch to the trunk revision it started from in Crucible?

Tags: svn, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

I am wondering how, using Crucible, I can include diff files that only contain the changes made in the branch from the point I branched off from my trunk. Currently, if I include something like change sets it counts every file in the branch as a new file and consequently doesn't show any diffs. Is there a way to do this?

I know I can go and select each file to do a diff from the branch version to the last trunk version but this would be very time consuming for the number of files I changed and I'd worry I might forget one. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Fisheye has a SQL like query langage called [EyeQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/EyeQL+Reference+Guide), you can construct a query to find all files modified on a branch

```
select revisions where modified on branch branch_name group by changeset
```

Comment: This helps get the list of files changed within a branch, but not how to diff those files against the current Trunk...  Would it just be to set the "div to" version to be the same as the latest version in trunk?  And how does this work if the versions aren't necessarily linear (meaning parallel development was going on in trunk and revision times overlap)

Answer (score -1):

`svn help diff`, 3-rd form: `diff OLD-URL[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]`

You have to diff trunk in latest revision before branching with latest revision in branch

Sample on real branch from real repo

**Branch**: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/Leichtbau-Deutsch/

```
>svn log -q -v --stop-on-copy http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/Leichtbau-Deutsch/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r28 | lazybadger | 2011-02-22 09:24:04 +0600 (Вт, 22 фев 2011)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/Leichtbau-Deutsch/Hello.de.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r27 | lazybadger | 2011-02-22 09:21:41 +0600 (Вт, 22 фев 2011)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/Leichtbau-Deutsch (from /trunk:26)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

"from /trunk:26" give OLD-URL[@OLDREV], highest revision in branch - NEW-URL[@NEWREV]

`svn diff http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk@26 http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/Leichtbau-Deutsch@28`

is needed result